# Is there an up-to-date package for migrating sails databases?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

[Sails-migrations](https://github.com/BlueHotDog/sails-migrations) only supports versions up to 0.10.5, and [sails-db-migrate](https://github.com/building5/sails-db-migrate) supports versions 0.10.x. What's the current recommended way to go about migrating Sails models?

On a side note, it does seem that migration and seeding does seem to be an afterthought with sails, yet it is an essential part to nearly every project. Is this an issue that's currently being worked on?